# Bash nested quote variable not working

Tags: linux, bash

I am running into an issue in a script I have.  I have the following:

```
~/test> echo bar > foo.txt; echo bar > foo.c
~/test> flags="--include \"*.txt\""
~/test> echo $flags
--include "*.txt"
~/test> grep -rHI $flags bar .
~/test> grep -rHI --include "*.txt" bar .
./foo.txt:bar
```

So, basically `grep -rHI $flags bar .` is not evaluating to the same as `grep -rHI --include "*.txt" bar .`   There is a way around this (using eval), but I would be interested in understanding why $flags is being treated differently than its literal expansion in this case.

---

Apparently, this is being marked as duplicate.  The quoted question deals with whitespace between elements, whereas, this question is about precedence of expansion as choroba pointed out.  (The two seem to have the same solution though).   I had found several references to using eval/array, but I didn't find a satisfactory answer as to what was the cause of the problem, and hence I was asking.

Comment: You *cannot* get embedded quotes in a string to work correctly for this. Don't try. Use an array. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for details.

Comment: @EtanReisner fortunately in this case embedded quotes are not needed. `flags="--include *.txt"` should work as intended.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, if the expansion of `$flags` is quoted and grep can handle seeing `--include *.txt` as one "word" of argument that will work but that's not a generally guarantee-able thing.

Comment: @EtanReisner It's not one word. `"$flags"` would be one word. Word splitting occurs way after parameter expansion.

Comment: @n.m. Notice I said "if the expansion of `$flags` is quoted" there? That's important because without that the wildcard is expanded and grep doesn't see it but instead sees a list of files (which isn't the same thing).

Comment: Ah, OK. But it isn't and need not be quoted here.

Comment: Actually `flags="--include *.txt"` does not quite work.  You'll notice the -r flag for grep.  I need it to look for *.txt files recursively (I oversimplified the question I suppose).   If you use `flags="include *.txt"`, then `*.txt` gets expanded to all files in the local directory, rather than to `*.txt`, which is what I would need.

Comment: @John you are right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the different behaviour is the order of expansions:

> Expansion  is  performed  on  the command line after it has been split into words. [...] The  order  of  expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and arithmetic
>          expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and  pathname
>          expansion. [...] Only  brace expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion can change the number of words of the
>          expansion; other expansions expand a single word to a single word.  The only exceptions to this are
>          the expansions of `"$@"` and `"${name[@]}"`

`flags=--include=*.txt` should be safe, though, unless you have a file named `--include=123.txt` somewhere, which you can prevent by quoting `"$flags"` in the command. But, as the quoted documentation says at the end, using an array is the best solution, if there are more than one flag:

```
flags=(--include '*.txt')
grep -rHi "${flags[@]}" bar .
```

Comment: Quotes aren't necessary on the assignment then either and then `"$flags"` at usage prevents the glob expansion.

Comment: It's no longer `flags`, then, is it? You're only supporting a single (one and only one -- zero won't work!) `flag` if quoting the expansion. Not quoting the expansion will work in this case if glob expansions are disabled, but it won't work in a more general case -- where, say, you might want to pass around filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Using an array is the only canonically correct, *generic* answer for passing multiple arguments with their original boundaries preserved.

```
flags=( --include '*.txt' )
grep -rHi "${flags[@]}" bar .
```